# How to store String values from an ArrayList<String> to an ArrayList<Object> of Objects

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to get the values of `listString` and save them to the list of objects `listFeed` and return `listFeed`. So far I used a Scanner to add date from `feedsFile` to my ArrayList `listString` but I don't know how to store those values in an ArrayList of Objects.

Here's the code snippet

```
public List<Feed> loadSubscribedFeeds(File feedsFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
    
    Scanner s = new Scanner(feedsFile);
    
    List<String> listString = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Feed> listFeed = new ArrayList<>();
    
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        listString.add(s.nextLine());
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < listString.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < listFeed.size(); j++) {
            
        }
    }
    
    return listFeed;
}
```

Here's the Feed class:

```
public class Feed implements Serializable, Comparable<Feed> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String url;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String publishedDateString;
    private List<Entry> entries;

    public Feed(String url) {
        super();
        this.url = url;
        this.entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        this.title = "";
        this.description = "";
        this.publishedDateString = "";
    }

    /**
     * Creates an instance of a Feed and transfers the feed
     * data form a SyndFeed object to the new instance.
     *
     * @param url        The URL string of this feed
     * @param sourceFeed The SyndFeed object holding the data for this feed instance
     */
    public Feed(String url, SyndFeed sourceFeed) {
        this(url);
        setTitle(sourceFeed.getTitle());
        setDescription(sourceFeed.getDescription());
        if (sourceFeed.getPublishedDate() != null)
            setPublishedDateString(FeaderUtils.DATE_FORMAT.format(sourceFeed.getPublishedDate()));
        for (SyndEntry entryTemp : sourceFeed.getEntries()) {
            Entry entry = new Entry(entryTemp.getTitle());
            entry.setContent(entryTemp.getDescription().getValue());
            entry.setLinkUrl(entryTemp.getLink());
            entry.setParentFeedTitle(getTitle());
            if (entryTemp.getPublishedDate() != null) {
                entry.setPublishedDateString(FeaderUtils.DATE_FORMAT.format(entryTemp.getPublishedDate()));
            }
            addEntry(entry);
        }
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title != null ? title : "";
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description != null ? description : "";
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setPublishedDateString(String publishedDateString) {
        this.publishedDateString = publishedDateString != null ? publishedDateString : "";
    }

    public String getPublishedDateString() {
        return publishedDateString;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short string containing a combination of meta data for this feed
     *
     * @return info string
     */
    public String getShortFeedInfo() {
        return getTitle() + " [" +
                getEntriesCount() + " entries]: " +
                getDescription() +
                (getPublishedDateString() != null && getPublishedDateString().length() > 0
                        ? " (updated " + getPublishedDateString() + ")"
                        : "");
    }

    public void addEntry(Entry entry) {
        if (entry != null) entries.add(entry);
    }

    public List<Entry> getEntries() {
        return entries;
    }

    public int getEntriesCount() {
        return entries.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (obj instanceof Feed)
                && ((Feed) obj).getUrl().equals(url);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return url.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getTitle();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Feed o) {
        return getPublishedDateString().compareTo(o.getPublishedDateString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Where (in which field) exactly in the `Feed` class you want to store the entries of the `ArrayList<String>`?

Comment: You don't need to loop over the `listFeed` items, you can call [`.add(new Feed(...))`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)) for every item in your `listString` list. Another way is to call [`.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#stream()) and then [`.map(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) with a lambda that takes a `String` and returns a `Feed`, then `.collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Thank you. The .add(new Feed(...)) works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to change your loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < listString.size(); i++) {
    listFeed.add( new Feed( listString.get(i) );
}
```

That way you're adding a new Feed object to the listFeed.

Another way you could do it is to use the stream api.

```
List<Feed> feeds = listString.stream().map( Feed::new ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

Your original technique with a loop is fine though.

A minor note, you do not need to call `super()` explicitly it will be called automatically if you don't use a different version of super.